# Действие по второму клику

Tags: javascript, jquery

Первый клик по пункту меню открывает всплывающий блок

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    if (window.innerWidth > 1150) {
      var container = $(".header__bottom-hover-menu.active");
      if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        container.removeClass('active');
        $('.header__bottom-hover-menu.active, .header__top, .header__bottom').removeClass('active');
        $('.header__nav-item > a.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.overlay').removeClass('active');
      }
    }
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.header__nav-item .submenu', function(e) {
    if (window.innerWidth > 1150) {
      let overlay = $('.overlay');

      if ($(this).parent().find('.header__bottom-hover-menu').length > 0) {
        $(this).parent().find('a.submenu').addClass('active');
        $(this).parent().find('.header__bottom-hover-menu').addClass('active');
        $('.header__top, .header__bottom').addClass('active');
        overlay.addClass('active');
      }
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

как сделать, чтобы по второму клику на пункте меню, осуществлялся переход в раздел сайта?

Comment: dblclick() не подойдёт?

Comment: можно и с dbclick(), продемонстрируйте плз решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    if (window.innerWidth > 1150) {
      var container = $(".header__bottom-hover-menu.active");
      if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        container.removeClass('active');
        $('.header__bottom-hover-menu.active, .header__top, .header__bottom').removeClass('active');
        $('.header__nav-item > a.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.overlay').removeClass('active');
      }
    }
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.header__nav-item .submenu', function(e) {
    if (window.innerWidth > 1150) {
      let overlay = $('.overlay');

      if ($(this).parent().find('.header__bottom-hover-menu').length > 0) {
        $(this).parent().find('a.submenu').addClass('active');
        $(this).parent().find('.header__bottom-hover-menu').addClass('active');
        $('.header__top, .header__bottom').addClass('active');
        overlay.addClass('active');
      }
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $(document).on('dblclick', '.header__nav-item .submenu', function() {
    window.location.assign("url");
  });
});
```

```css
.header__nav-item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
}

.header__nav-item .submenu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header__nav-item">
  <div class="submenu">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а можно чтобы на месте window.location.assign("url"); рандомный юрл срабатывал, который в вёрстке?

Comment: да, нужно создать массив который будет содержать все ссылки, и с помощю функции рандомного числа выводить случайный елемент, да и если вой ответ подходит отметьте галочкой